# Is this Spring Boot starter log4j2 configuration correct?

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot, log4j2

## My Goal

My goal is to use the [log4j2 API](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/log4j-api/) for application logging, while being able to capture Spring Boot log messages in a file separate from the main application logging file.  For testing purposes I'm logging the two files containing application and spring message to the directory `src/test/resources/log`.

## Question

It seems to be working fine, but I just wanted to a community double check in case I'm missing anything WRT my pom.xml dependency configuration and logging configuration (I've seen a lot of different variations in other SO posts)?

### Maven POM Configuration

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.4.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j2</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

### src/test/resources/log4j2.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration>
<Properties>
    <Property name="log-path">src/test/resources/log</Property>
</Properties>
<Appenders>
    <Console name="Console-Appender" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
        <PatternLayout>
            <pattern>
                [%-5level] %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %c{1} - %msg%n
            </pattern>>
        </PatternLayout>
    </Console>
    <File name="App-File-Appender" fileName="${log-path}/application.log" >
        <PatternLayout>
            <pattern>
                [%-5level] %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %c{1} - %msg%n
            </pattern>
        </PatternLayout>
    </File>
    <File name="Spring-File-Appender" fileName="${log-path}/spring.log" >
        <PatternLayout>
            <pattern>
                [%-5level] %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %c{1} - %msg%n
            </pattern>
        </PatternLayout>
    </File>
</Appenders>
<Loggers>
    <Logger name="org.springframework" level="info" additivity="false">
        <AppenderRef ref="Spring-File-Appender"/>
        <AppenderRef ref="Console-Appender"/>
    </Logger>
    <Logger name="com.example" level="info" additivity="false">
        <AppenderRef ref="App-File-Appender"/>
        <AppenderRef ref="Console-Appender"/>
     </Logger>
    <Root level="info">
        <AppenderRef ref="Console-Appender"/>
    </Root>
</Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

Comment: *It seems to be working fine, but I just wanted to a community double check*. Time to visit - [CodeReview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Sweet - just signed up - thanks for the heads up and thanks for the review @Remko Popma

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All looks fine to me. If anything I would put an explicit log level on the root logger so that operations people know what to expect.